Would a question regarding a list of outdated sports techniques be appropriate?
I am interested in techniques that were used in the past to have a high(er) chance of winning in certain sports, but are getting more and more obsolete these days.
An example is the one-handed backhand in tennis. Yes, there are still highly-ranked professional tennis players that employ it (including Dimitrov, Wawrinka, Gasquet, Tsitsipas, and Musetti) but the top 10 of men's singles players is currently dominated by players with a two-handed backhand (Djokovic, Sinner, Alcaraz, etc.). This was not the case in the past. Federer, Sampras, Edberg, Lendl, and Becker all had single-handed backhand techniques.
This would be an example if a [list] or [big-list] question. I am active in the Math Stack Exchange and Math Overflow communities, where such questions are considered appropriate. I was wondering whether the above question is appropriate for this venue. I've read moderator Joe's Meta answer on list-based questions, where he states that such questions are sometimes appropriate, but sometimes they aren't. In any case, I don't think this question is opinion-based: it is an objectively verifiable fact that the one-handed backhand is being adopted less and less often by highly-ranked professional tennis players. Moreover, I don't think there are too many possible answers in this case - an objection raised in this answer.
Is this question appropriate for Sports SE?

My instant take here is that the list would be too big. Strategies evolve with time in every sport:

Competitors are are bigger and stronger today than they were in the past
In many sports, technology has evolved in a way that enables radically different strategies - consider wooden vs metal vs carbon fiber racquets.
In many sports, strategies have evolved to be riskier and more aggressive - e.g. the increase in passing in American football, 3 pointers in basketball, etc.

There may be some "pure" athletic sports like the 100m sprint where things are pretty similar now to 50 years ago, but I think they're very much in the minority.

Fair enough. And what if I ask multiple questions, each aimed at finding out what techniques are outdated for a specific sport? So they'd be of the form: What techniques used to be popular and effictive at the professional level in [sport X], but are nowadays deemed outdated practices?

I don't think those would be good either.  Just too generic/opinion based.  What's the point of the question? Why are you asking it?

I would not phrase my answer as suggesting "sometimes acceptable, sometimes not".  My answer was that it is generally not acceptable, but we occasionally make exceptions - think 99% not, 1% yes.
In the case of sporting achievements, we make that exception here largely because, while those are "lists", the list itself is an answer to a specific question - and a common thing sports fans want to know.  Thus, well worth the extra work.  It's also a single, complete answer; the entries individually are not useful, but the collection itself is the answer, and it is feasible to expect that it is the complete answer, assuming the answerer made a decent effort.
Broadly, for a question to be acceptable that has a list answer, I would suggest thinking: is the list itself answering completely a question (at a point in time)?  Or is the list just a collection of answers, and/or is that list unlikely to be complete.
Your question asks for a list, each entry on which might be an answer to the question; and the list will never really be complete, as the number of things answering it might be in the hundreds, even if focused on just one sport.  The answers are also largely opinion based - your example of one-handed backhands for example is a great example; maybe that entry counts, maybe not, given that current players use that technique.
